# MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: ... column: dept_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know there are similar questions here, but for some reason they just don't work for me. Here, I can't even find which column is repeated. The basic idea of the system is that using a join on deptId (FK), I can get all the employees in a certain department.

I have reproduced below the relevant code:

Employee.java

```
    package com.tvlk.advDemo.model;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="employees")
    public class Employee implements Serializable {
        private long id;
        private String name;
        private String designation;
        private long deptId;
        private Department department;

        public Employee() {

        }

        public Employee(String name, String designation, long deptId) {
            this.name = name;
            this.designation = designation;
            this.deptId = deptId;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Column(name = "designation", nullable = false)
        public String getDesignation() {
            return designation;
        }
        public void setDesignation(String designation) {
            this.designation = designation;
        }

    //    @Column(name = "deptId", nullable = false)
        public long getDeptId() {
            return deptId;
        }
        public void setDeptId(long deptId) {
            this.deptId = deptId;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "deptId", nullable = false)
        public Department getDepartment() {
            return department;
        }

        public void setDepartment(Department department){
            this.department = department;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", designation=" + designation + ", deptId=" + deptId
                    + "]";
        }
    }
```

Here is Department.java

```
package com.tvlk.advDemo.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name="departments")
public class Department implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String deptName;
    private String deptHead;
    private long budget;
    private List<Employee> employees;


    public Department(){

    }

    public Department(long id, String deptName, String deptHead, long budget)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.deptHead = deptHead;
        this.deptName = deptName;
        this.budget = budget;
    }

    @Id
    public long getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(long id) {this.id = id; }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getDeptName(){return deptName;}
    public void setDeptName(String deptName){this.deptName = deptName; }

    @Column(name = "deptHead", nullable = false)
    public String getDeptHead(){return deptHead; }
    public void setDeptHead(String deptHead){this.deptHead = deptHead; }

    @Column(name = "budget", nullable = false)
    public long getBudget(){return budget;}
    public void setBudget(long budget){this.budget = budget; }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id", targetEntity = Employee.class)
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return this.employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, I am quite new to springboot and hibernate. Note that I am making REST APIs for CRUD operations using H2.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have multiple fields that contains same name. That's the reason for repeated column.

Example:

```
 private long deptId;



`@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "deptId", nullable = false)
 public Department getDepartment() {
     return department;
 }`
```

There is already a column named `depId` (long type in ur field) and again you are trying to add `Department` with same column name ( `@JoinColumn(name = "deptId", nullable = false)` ) in your Joincolumn name. Try to change the JoinColumn name or add different column name to long datatype field.